# Assistance Exercises for Full Snatch

Tags: olympic, snatch

I'm a serious recreational lifter. I enjoy doing the power and Olympic lifts but find the over-head squat portion  of the full snatch to be difficult. I can easily do the squat-clean and press with 185 but I find the full snatch difficult with even 115 lbs. I would like to know some good exercises and drills for helping me improve the full snatch. I appreciate any advice you can offer.

Comment: I would look into mobility issues first and foremost.

Comment: FYI, Rippetoe doesn't mention any assistance exercises in 3rd edition starting strength for the power snatch.

Comment: I have very good mobility. I can do a squat clean and nearly bounce my butt of the ground when I go into the squat. So if there is any sort of mobility issue it might be in my shoulders, but I don't think that is the case. Maybe I just need to spend a few weeks doing daily over-had squats and increasing the weight? It really seems like a balance issue to me.

Comment: How are you losing the lift?

Comment: Sorry, Dave. I forgot to respond. The issue I have is with the overhead portion if the lift (it either falls forward or backward). I have designed a routine that I will post that combines some stretches and exercises for mobility and some assistance lifts. If I notice a good improvement in a few weeks I will post what I have come up with.

Comment: I'd be really interested in what you come up with. I would guess things like shrugs, rows, pull-ups/chin-ups, overhead press would all assist your full snatch.

Comment: I have some drills as well as some interesting exercises like overhead squat press. But I'll be honest. I think the major issue is my shoes... I'll post a follow up at the end of this week if I can.

Answer (score 1):

This could be due to shoulder stability - work your OH squats as much as you can, plus supplemental exercises like KB windmills and TGU will be of help as well.